# Avoid rounding errors and fractions in Prices of QuoteLineItems

Tags: quotelineitem, pricing

We are expecting problems with decimals in our Sales Prices (aka [UnitPrice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quotelineitem.htm)). We are setting up a Sales process (Advanced Currency Management enabled). Sales reps are to sell goods for the product of `Sales Price times Quantity`, i.e. based on the Subtotal of the QuoteLineItem, not its Sales Price itself. Sales reps are flexible to offer any prices above `List Price times Quantity`. (In reality it's more complicated, because the lower limit is lessened by sold quantities, i.e. an implicit volume discount is applied.)

For the sales process itself, selling prices of single products are irrelevant, explicit discounts are shown off and both Total Price and Sales Price (incl. the quantity) are to look nice, i.e. decimal places and numbers like 2001 are to be avoided.

There are about two dozen different prices in just one PriceBook and quantities can be anything. Example:

- For a given product, $60 x 13 = $780 is the lower limit.
- Sales wants to sell for $1000, but allows an explicit discount of 10%,
- i.e. Sales sells for $900 after applying the discount.
- Unknown to Sales, the calculated Sales Price is $1000 / 13 = $76.92307692...

How can this be avoided?

1. Salesforce stores number fields to maximum precision, not just 2 decimals, even currency fields. But storing Sales Prices like the one above doesn't look right, and some rounding problems might come back to us at some point. Or not?!
2. Sales reps could be forced not to sell anything that can't be divided cleanly. We could auto-correct the Sales rep's choice of $1000 to $1001 and then apply a 10% discount, giving us $899.90. This doesn't look too bad, although the subtotal of $1001 would need to be explained during the sales process ("our system makes such funny prices"), and we were sort of lucky with $899.90 - other results looked more ugly.
3. We could create our own fields on the QuoteLineItem object and implement a custom price logic. We are unsure about the consequences and prefer using standard fields.
4. We don't want to use CPQ.

The format of price fields can be expanded to 8 decimals (e.g. mentioned [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sales_core.pdf)), but this wouldn't help. I guess I lack the Sales Cloud certification :-/ Any documentation I should have consulted?

Comment: Formula field and round the result however you want.

Comment: Does this mean you would opt for option 3 and create your own custom QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice field? A field which doesn't hold the exact result of the division of Subtotal and Quantity, but this value rounded? And at the same time populate QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice with the exactest value possible?

Comment: Yes. There are well known tradeoffs with not using standard fields but in our experience the cons are manageable.

Comment: Rounded two decimal places of Sales Prices would potentially be forwarded to third party systems. This represents a problem no matter if we do so based on standard Sales Prices or formula fields that conceal the many decimals that result from the sales process.